# How do I achieve a valid UUID?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

I've been using Chrome's bluetooth APIs for a project, but I seem to have run into an issue since playing with it last week.

I am able to scan for nearby devices, and display those in a list. When it comes to actually connecting, I get this error: "*Connection failed: Invalid UUID*"

The UUID in question, fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66, appears to be valid. It is the same UUID that I use in my Android application.

The documentation doesn't seem to help. What exactly is causing this error, and how can I solve it? Below is my manifest.

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Bluetooth Bridge", 
  "version": "1.1",
  "icons": {
     "16": "icon.png",
     "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "app": {
     "background": {
         "scripts": ["main.js"]
     }
  },
  "permissions": [
     {"fileSystem": ["directory"]},
      {
         "bluetooth": [
           {
             "socket": true,
             "uuids": ["fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66", "8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66"],
             "low_energy": true
           }
         ]
      }
  ],
  "bluetooth": {
      "socket": true,
      "uuids": ["fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66", "8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66"],
      "low_energy": true
  }
```

}

And here is my code:

```
function connectTo(address) {
    app.getElementById("bluetoothconnect").innerHTML = "Trying to establish connection to "+device_names[address];
    var uuid = '8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66';
    console.log(uuid);
    var onConnectedCallback = function() {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        console.log("Connection failed: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          app.getElementById("bluetoothconnect").innerHTML = "Could not connect. "+chrome.runtime.lastError.message+".";
      } else {
        // Profile implementation here.
          console.log("Profile Implementation");
        app.getElementById('bluetoothconnect').innerHTML = "Successfully connected to "+device_names[address];
        app.getElementById('service').disabled = false;
        app.getElementById('devicenames').setAttribute('class', 'disabled');
          app.getElementById('service').addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log("click");
            startService(); 
          });
          app.getElementById('disconnect').addEventListener('click', function() {
            chrome.bluetoothSocket.disconnect(window.socketId);        
              app.getElementById('bluetoothstatus').innerHTML = "Nothing doing";
              app.getElementById('bluetoothconnect').innerHTML = "Not connected";
              app.getElementById('service').disabled = false;
              app.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = true;
          });
      }
    };

    chrome.bluetoothSocket.create(function(createInfo) {
        window.socketId = createInfo.socketId;
      chrome.bluetoothSocket.connect(createInfo.socketId,
        address, uuid, onConnectedCallback);
    });   
}
```